# In SQL server have some tables that tables is taken from linked server but it is not reflecting?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have one linked server and I have one SQL Server db. In SQL server I have some tables that are taken from linked server. But while inserting and updating the tables it is not reflecting in SQL server. I want to reflect this data in both SQL server db and linked server? Can this be done?

Comment: Linked servers are used only for pulling data from them (therefore, only `SELECT`s). What exactly do you mean by reflecting data in both your local and linked server?

Comment: If this is sql-server, why you tagged as mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to update the linked server this way?

```
     UPDATE T2
          SET    T2.Field = T1.Field
     FROM   [LinkedServer].DATABASE.dbo.table2 AS T2
     JOIN   table1 AS T1
            ON T1.id = T2.id
```